# Java Robot not clicking in the correct spot

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am using a Java robot to click the screen in specific locations. However it is clicking in the wrong spot. It seems random how off the click is. For example I wanted to click (540, 90), (669, 90), (795, 90). I downloaded a program which displays the coordinates of my mouse on the screen and I saw that it instead clicked at (555, 98), (698, 88), (819, 91) respectively. Here's the code for those clicks:

```
public void start() {
    click(540, 90, 10);
    robot.delay(1000);
    click(669, 90, 10);
    robot.delay(1000);
    click(795, 90, 10);
}

public void click(int x, int y, int delayBetween) {
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.delay(delayBetween);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

I've used Robot in the past and it's always worked well, so I'm not really sure why the mouse would not be displayed in the correct position. If anyone has any suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add delay after mouseMove and check whether it makes a difference?

Comment: @KDM Just tried that, and I got the same incorrect coordinates.

Comment: I doubt your program that is displaying the coordinates.

Comment: @KDM But that wouldn't explain why the mouse is not clicking in the correct location. I can physically see it clicking in the wrong position, changing it's y coordinate, when they should all be 90. That's why I downloaded the program in the first place because I could see that the Robot was clicking incorrectly.

Comment: @shadowwarcher Try setting `setAutoWaitForIdle` on the robot object.

Comment: I experienced similar problem on Windows 10 with 4K display when scale is >100%
So it might be well known issue:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196030
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186063

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko This was actually the first thing I attempted, I set my display scale back to 100% from 125% but it still didn't work.

Comment: @shadowarcher, reboot your OS after setting scale to 100%. This works for me.

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko I tried rebooting and the problem persists. Plus if the issue was due to scaling, I would expect to at least see uniform scaling, i.e. multiply the expected value by 1.25 for 125%, however the y-value is changing, when it should remain the same, wouldn't this mean that the issue is not due to scaling?